# Can the browser start an application on the user's 'phone?

Tags: javascript, android, browser, cross-browser

I am implementing a server. There is no client, just the user's browser.

For one functionality I have, until now, always redirected to a URL and let the user's browser handle it.

However, now someone wants me, as a result of user action, to "launch an app on the user's smartphone".

Forgetting for the moment that the user might not even have the app installed, is this possible?

If I returned a web page with some JavaScript, would it be allowed to launch an app? This would seem to have some security implications and I doubt that it can be done.

I dimly remember once reading from a PC's serial port from a web page, but I had to jump through hoops with an ActiveX control and a COM DLL to do that. Since that required Internet Explorer & Windows, it's no longer an acceptable solution. My question pertains to all browsers and to Android & iOs (although a solution which also works for Windows, Linux & Mac would be nice to have).

I am asking here, seeking a definitive answer.

Comment: I updated my answer have a look if you have already saw it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you are talking about the default web browser or one created by you.

Usually when you want to launch an app from a browser you have to define this in your manifest using **intent filter**:

```
<intent-filter>
  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="mysite.com"/>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_ACTION" />
</intent-filter>
```

So if you are talking about the default browser **you can not**, but if it is a browser coded by you then you can start an activity like always with intents.

**EDIT** 
I am not sure if this works, but try to make your links look like this and have a test:

```
<a href="intent:#Intent;action=my_action;end">Link to my app</a>
```

Comment: I am thinking about serving my own web page with some https://cordova.apache.org/ and trying to do what I want in JS